# Понимание работы ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

Нужна небольшая помощь в `ResultSet`. `ResultSet` -  это объект который имеет курсор, который в свою очередь передвигается по мере чтения данных из таблицы.

То есть по сути он не имеет данных, кроме как сведений о курсоре?

И каким образом `fetchSize` влияет на `ResultSet`(интересно не то что делает метод, а именно как он работает в контексте) ибо у нас присутствуют только данные о курсоре имеются в нем?

Comment: Это некий стек коллекции, собранный через подготовленный запрос, для возврата выборки и прохода по ней, если это потребуется.

Comment: @And То есть это все таки коллекция? тогда мы следовательно можем получить outofmemory?

Comment: Естественно, возвращает коллекцию строк выборки. Конечно можем получить `OutOfMemory`. Это будет отражать переполненный буфер памяти и вы, сами сможете в этом убедиться, если сделаете большую выборку, чем отведено для самого результата. За частую это бывает, когда данных больше, чем отведено памяти для запроса.

Comment: @And Ну я внизу уже ответил почему задал такой вопрос. Ответьте сообщением, я вам плюсик поставлю.

Comment: А какой смысл от ответа, если вы, уже выбрали для вас правильный ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> То есть по сути он не имеет данных, кроме как сведений о курсоре?

Нет, это не верно.

---

В определении [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) сказано:

> Что это - таблица данных, представляющая набор результатов базы данных, который обычно генерируется путем выполнения утверждения, выполняющего запрос к базе данных.

[`getFetchSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getFetchSize()) определяет сколько записей считывает запрос, и устаналивается в утверждении `Statement`:

> [`int getFetchSize () throws SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getFetchSize())
>
> Получает количество строк набора результатов, которое является
>   размером выборки по умолчанию для объектов `ResultSet`, сгенерированных
>   из этого объекта `Statement`. Если этот объект `Statement` не установил
>   размер выборки, вызвав метод `setFetchSize`, возвращаемое значение будет
>   специфичным для реализации.

Comment: Давайте сначала. То есть ResultSer это определенный набор данных. Устанавливая setFetchSize() мы устанавливаем определенный размер выборки(за раз). И если таблица будет ~1 000 000 без setFetchSize() мы просто получим исключение, от драйвера о слишком большом размере ResultSet.

Comment: По умолчанию устанавливается размер выборки *если таблица будет ~1 000 000 без `setFetchSize() `*.

Comment: Но по умолчанию может стоять возвращение всех данных из таблицы. И при этом мы все же получим исключение о слишком большом размере резалтсэта?

Comment: *возвращаемое значение будет специфичным для реализации*

Comment: возвращаемое значение будет специфичным для реализации.....RDMS. Верно?

Comment: драйвера я так понимаю

Comment: Остается лишь добавить что драйвер ПОЧТИ всегда специфичен для RDBMS) ну я всегда так и предполагал. Просто недавно на собесе, один человек сказал что resultset ничего не возвращает и только двигает курсор, и когда я ответил как описали вы он сказал что я не прав. Он сказал что ошибки не будет при 1000 000 000 000, а я сказал что будет либо outofmemory, либо что-то типо manyrowsofqueryresult(непомню точно что postgres драйвер выбрасывает).